# How to find out what set_data expects

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make an animation with matplotlib, in this case a 3D scatter plot. I'm hitting a problem that I absolutely always hit when I try to do this, which is that I don't know what arguments I should pass to `set_data`, and I don't know how to find out. In this case, it apparently expects two arguments, despite it being a 3d plot.

Since I've experienced related problems often, rather than asking about the specifics of the particular plot I'm trying to animate, I will ask the general question: given an element of a MatPlotLib plot, how can I determine what arguments its `set_data` method expects, either by interrogating it, or by knowing where it's documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an example for an [Animated 3D random walk from the MatPlotLib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/animation/random_walk.html) documentation:

```
def update_lines(num, dataLines, lines):
    for line, data in zip(lines, dataLines):
        # NOTE: there is no .set_data() for 3 dim data...
        line.set_data(data[0:2, :num])
        line.set_3d_properties(data[2, :num])
    return lines
```

So as confusing as you discovered it is `set_data` by itself is not meant for 3D data, as well as according to the [docs](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_data) it accepts:

> 2D array (rows are x, y) or two 1D arrays

Looking more at this example we can see that the [`set_3d_properties`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3D.set_3d_properties) has been used altogether.

This whole `update_lines` was set as a callback parameter for [`animation.FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation).

Comment: Oh wow, ok, that's completely ridiculous, but apparently the right answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually to find the documentation you can either search it up online (e.g [doc for set_data](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_data)) or from a python prompt you can use the help function, which will show you the docstring of the object (can be used on a module/function/class etc) if it has any.
For example if you want to know what the datetime.datetime.now does (I dont have mathplotlib install to use it on it):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> help(datetime.datetime.now)
Help on built-in function now:

now(tz=None) method of builtins.type instance
    Returns new datetime object representing current time local to tz.

      tz
        Timezone object.

    If no tz is specified, uses local timezone.
```

Comment: Hmm, I guess maybe I should have asked more specifically about my plot, then. My object is indeed a Line2D, so that's the right documentation page ... but ... it's a 3D plot. I need to give it coordinates in three dimensions, not two, and that documentation doesn't mention how to do that.